# PHP array display does not display all columns

Tags: php, arrays, forms, xhtml, psql

I managed to get the checkboxes to POST the data and displays each on the checkout page but the problem I have is when it gets to 4th column it stops when it hits a certain char limit also how would I turn this into a table on the checkout page.

Database snippet code:

```
print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]"value='. $getColumn[0]. $getColumn[1].     $getColumn[2]. $getColumn[3]. $getColumn[4].  $getColumn[5].$getColumn[6].$getColumn[7].$getColumn[8].$getColumn[9].'</td>';
for ($column = 1; $column < pg_num_fields($res); $column++)
{   
print "<td>" . $getColumn[$column] . "</td>"; 
}
}
print '</table>'
```

Checkout page

```
<?php

echo "<hr />\n";
$res = pg_query ($con, "select count(ref) from music");
$a = pg_fetch_row($res);
echo "<p>Total " . $a[0] . " music in database.</p>";

echo "<table border='1'>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Artist</th><th>Composer</th><th>Genre</th><th>Title</th><th>Album</th><th>Label</th>     <th>Price</th><th>Description</th>\n";
echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";
$res=pg_query($con, "SELECT * from music ORDER BY ref");
while ($a = pg_fetch_array ($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
  // htmlspecialchars converts things like & to HTML entity codes
      echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($a[$j], ENT_QUOTES) . "</td>";
    }
 echo "</tr>\n";
 }
echo "</tbody>\n</table>";



?>
```

Comment: I would bet it isn't hitting any "character limit" but rather the output includes a value which breaks your HTML. View the page source and see if it's all there. You need to escape it for HTML output like `htmlspecialchars($getColumn[$column'])` or `echo "<p>". htmlspecialchars($selected) ."</p>";` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: I also note that the `value=` attribute is not quoted. If there's any whitespace, it will not be properly parsed by HTML.  You need to make sure it results as `value="abcdefg 1234567"` surrounded by quotes. Also missing a space before `value=` after `name="check_list[]"` And the `<input>` tag is missing its `>`

Comment: thank you this fixed the output but now i need to put this into a table i'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Edit your question above to show an example of how you want the output HTML to look. It isn't completely clear, though I suspect I see what you're getting at.

Comment: okay i have edited this is the layout i want just need it to display the rows within that table that have been selected from checkbox which is check_list

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, you are tried to do the following:

```
print '<table>';
for ($column = 1; $column < pg_num_fields($res); $column++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="'.$getColumn[$column] .'" /></td>';
    print "<td>" . $getColumn[$column] . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: I can not help you, if you don't tell me, what errors do you get.